# What are the purposes of each step in train-evaluate-predict in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

What do each of the stages do? I understand that for neural nets in nlp, the train will find the best parameters for the word embedding. But what is the purpose of the evaluation step? What is it supposed to do? How is that different from the prediction phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Training, evaluation and prediction are the three main steps of training a model ( basically in any ML framework ) and to **move a model from research/development to production**.

**Training:**

A suitable ML architecture is selected based on the problem which needs to be solved. **Hyperparameter optimization** is carried out to fine-tune the model. The model is then trained on the data for a certain number of epochs. **Metrics such as loss, accuracy, MSE are monitored.**

**Evaluation:**

> We need to move the model to production. The model in the production
>   stage will only make inferences and hence we require the best model
>   possible. So, in order to evaluate or test the model based on some
>   predefined levels, the evaluation phase is carried out.

Evaluation is mostly carried out on the data which is a subset of the original dataset. Training and evaluations splits are made while preprocessing the data. **Metrics are calculated in order to check the performance of the model on the evaluation dataset.**

> The evaluation data has been never seen by the model as it is not trained on it. Hence, the model's best performance is expected here.

**Prediction:**

After the testing of the model, we can move it to production. In the production phase, models only make an inference ( predictions ) on the data given to them. No training takes place here.

> Even after a thorough examination, the model tends to make
>   mispredictions. Hence, in the production stage, we can receive
>   interactive feedback from the users about the performance of the
>   model.

Now,

> But what is the purpose of the evaluation step? What is it supposed to
>   do? How is that different from the prediction phase?

Evaluation is to make the model better for most cases through which it will come across. Predictions are made to check for other problems which are not related to performance.

Comment: Hey thanks for the thorough explanation! I have a question though, is "evaluation data has never been never seen" a typo? If it's a typo, then it has never been seen by the model so why would it be faster than say the prediction phase? I still don't quite understand how prediction is entirely different from evaluation. Is the only difference that evaluation has some metric to calculate the performance? What other problems are checked in the prediction phase?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. In prediction phase, the model is in use by real-world users whereas in the evaluation phase, it is tested by developers using different metrics.

Comment: Also, while understanding the difference between evaluation and prediction, do not consider the speed of each phase. It's a different factor.